# AWS - would creating EBS snapshot ever restart/reboot/terminate running instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am unable to undertstand this

Would creating EBS snapshot ever restart/reboot/terminate running instance?

If I understand creating an AMI reboots instance for maintaining data integrity/consistency.

Does that apply to EBS as well? Is it guaranteed one or another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a snapshot of an attached volume that is in use. However, snapshots only capture data that has been written to your Amazon EBS volume at the time the snapshot command is issued. This might exclude any data that has been cached by any applications or the operating system. If you can pause any file writes to the volume long enough to take a snapshot, your snapshot should be complete. However, if you can't pause all file writes to the volume, you should unmount the volume from within the instance, issue the snapshot command, and then remount the volume to ensure a consistent and complete snapshot. You can remount and use your volume while the snapshot status is pending.

So creating a EBS snapshot will never reboot the instance as you can take the snapshot even when the volume is attached. But best practice suggest stoping the instance unmount volume and then take snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for the resonse. I understand that. My question is about when creating an EBS snapshot and not AMI. Would instance reboot / restart ever if EBS snapshot is created?